# Import/Export errors with morbo when using Mango

Tags: perl, mongodb, ubuntu, mojolicious

I'm working on a fresh Ubuntu vm, I've imported Mojolicious, Mango and MongoDB all through terminal (apt-gets and curls) but when I try and run any project that implements Mango - using command: 
    morbo project/script/project

It returns the following error:

```
Couldn't load application from file "project/script/project": "dumper" is not exported by         the Mojo::Util module
Can't continue after import errors at /etc/perl/Mango.pm line 10
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /etc/perl/Mango.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /home/user/project/script/../lib/project.pm line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/user/project/script/../lib/project.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 94) line 1.
```

The Mojo::Util and Mango.pm are all unedited dependencies as downloaded.
Never had any of these problems getting it to run on windows so I'm a bit lost where to start looking for a solution now.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: funny question title (for a non perl expert) :)

Answer (score 1):

Much the same as with other languages such as python or ruby, using **system** perl is a **bad idea** and will cause you headaches down the track. What will also cause you problems (much like this one) is pulling down packages "via curl" and simply unpacking to a directory. You need to **install** most things properly, and there are tools to manage **both** of these problems.

> For instance, the underlying [MongoDB](http://search.cpan.org/~friedo/MongoDB-0.702.2/lib/MongoDB.pm) driver module **requires** a C compiler to **build** as part of it's **install** process.

You may have installed that one via `apt-get`. But it is not recommended.

I would recommend using an "environment based" installation such as [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) or [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) in order to "manage" your installed perl installation, and **not** "mess around" with the system installed perl.

In either case, both will integrate well with the *excellent* [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7001/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) module and utility. This allows you to **install** packages from CPAN in a correct way, so that your application works and you avoid errors.

All options allow methods so you can install the modules locally for your application in this way. [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) may be better for you if you need "per application" separation on the same machine in this way.

Use the **correct** methods, and you are far less likely to run into problems.